# Regra de negócio em um sistema pessoal

Tags: regra-de-negócio

**Conceito de regra de negócio**

> São declarações sobre a forma da empresa fazer negócio. Elas refletem
>   políticas do negócio. As organizações com isto têm políticas para
>   satisfazer os objetivos do negócio, satisfazer clientes, fazer bom uso
>   dos recursos, e obedecer às leis ou convenções gerais do negócio.

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regras_de_neg%C3%B3cio

Tentando compreender o que são as regras de negócio:

> “São declarações sobre a forma da empresa fazer negócio. ”

Eu posso desenvolver um sistema pessoal, para mim mesmo, e esse conceito ainda se aplica a esse caso?

Por exemplo, vamos supor que desenvolvi um sistema para as minhas caminhadas ou corridas. Esse sistema registra a distância percorrida. Essa distância pode ser em metros ou quilômetros. O sistema registra o tempo gasto na caminhada. Esse tempo pode ser em segundos, minutos ou horas. O sistema registra a data e a hora da caminhada. Posso acessar as minhas caminhadas através de um histórico.

> “Esse sistema registra a distância percorrida.”
>
> “Essa distância pode ser em metros ou quilômetros.”
>
> “O sistema registra o tempo gasto na caminhada.”

Essas são regras de negócio?

Se sim, voltando ao conceito: elas são declarações que representam como a empresa (no caso, eu mesmo) faz (faço) seus (meus) negócios?
Se isso está correto, o que significa “negócios”? Em um âmbito comercial imagino que seja venda de produto, pagamento, descontos, etc., o que não se aplica nesse meu exemplo de sistema de caminhada.

No meu exemplo de sistema de caminhada, percebo que as regras de negócio são aquilo o que o sistema faz: “Esse sistema registra a distância percorrida. ”; e também são detalhes, restrições ou condições daquilo que faz: “Essa distância pode ser em metros ou quilômetros. ”. É isso o que entendo como regra de negócio. Estou equivocado em alguma coisa?

Comment: Será que consideraram todas as minhas dúvidas neste post antes de querer fechá-lo ou negativá-lo?

Comment: Há outros posts sobre regras de negócios, mas neste, além de abordar o conceito geral, eu também as questiono dentro de um sistema específico. Também pergunto se determinadas coisas, desse sistema em específico, são regras de negócios.

Answer (score 1):

Entenda regras de negócio como o que define  o que teu programa fará. Indiferente de você ter ou não um negócio.

É a maneira como o sistema se comportará. No caso do teu sistema pessoal para controlar as caminhadas, as regras serão para calcular o tempo percorrido, transformar o tempo de horas para minuto ou vice e versa, etc.

Em resumo, é o que dá sentido ao software.

Answer (score 1):

No seu sistema pessoal você pode não permitir, por exemplo, que o email cadastrado seja do GMAIL ou que o usuário tenha mais de 18 anos ou obriga a verificação do numero do telefone, enfim; isso são regras de negócio.

As restrições que seu sistema impoe ao usuário para atingir o objetivo são as regras de seu negócio.

Comment: Então, eu defini dessa maneira: as regras de negócio são aquilo o que o sistema faz: “Esse sistema registra a distância percorrida. ”; e também são detalhes, restrições ou condições daquilo que faz: “Essa distância pode ser em metros ou quilômetros. ”. Só não tenho certeza se o que o sistema faz ou deve fazer pode ser uma regra de negócio.

Comment: Não exatamente o que ele faz, mas as regras que ele impõe para fazer.

Comment: “Esse sistema registra a distância percorrida. ” é uma regra de negócio?

Comment: Ou então "O sistema deve registrar a distância percorrida" é uma regra de negócio?

Comment: Não. O que o sistema faz não é uma regra.

Comment: Entendi, essa era uma de minhas dúvidas.

Comment: @HeyJoe Acho que neste caso, regras de negócio seriam coisas como "Se a distância for menor que X, o sistema deve fazer A e B", "distâncias com valores Y e Z são descartadas", "distâncias maiores que X são notificadas para usuários Fulano e Ciclano" e por aí vai. De maneira geral, a ideia é essa. Eu costumo dizer que, se temos que perguntar pro cliente qual deve ser o comportamento do sistema em determinada situação, a resposta que ele dá (geralmente) vira uma regra de negócio :)

Comment: @hkotsubo O que o sistema deverá fazer não é uma regra de negócio, então pensei que seria um requisito de software. Li neste link https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-requisitos-de-software/29580 sobre requisitos e o conceito parece ser o mesmo da regra de negócio.

Comment: "O sistema deverá fazer isso e aquilo", tem algum termo técnico para isso? Não sei se estão conseguindo entender a minha dúvida. Na verdade, no link que passei, o conceito que disse ser o mesmo de regra de negócio era o conceito geral apresentado no texto. Depois, na classificação dos requisitos, ele define o que o sistema deve fazer como Requisito Funcional.

Comment: @HeyJoe *"O sistema deverá fazer isso"* é um requisito. Mas há casos em que a fronteira não é muito clara. Ex: *"O sistema só aceitará cadastros até a data X"* é um requisito ou regra de negócio? Alguns dirão que **com certeza** é o primeiro, outros que é o segundo, pra outros tanto faz (e alguns polemizam esta questão até demais, na minha opinião). Eu não ficaria tão focado na definição exata, o importante é que estas coisas sejam bem definidas (sem ambiguidades, sem margem para interpretações erradas) e todos tenham o mesmo entendimento delas. O resto é "preciosismo acadêmico" :)

Answer (score 1):

De uma forma resumida, a definição de um sistema passa por algumas fases. Após essa definição é que o sistema entra em "produção". A parte acadêmica que cuida dessa parte é chamada Engenharia de Software. Quando digo resumida é porque o processo todo é bastante complexos e com muitos detalhes.

Embora a sua questão seja para um sistema pessoal, o que muda é que você acaba fazendo todos os papéis no processo. O fato do sistema ser pessoal não muda a metodologia que você emprega no desenvolvimento, muda apenas a complexidade e o esforço que você precisa empregar e permite que você possa abreviar o tempo para chegar no final.

Vou descrever essas primeiras fases porque eu entendo ser mais fácil de entender tendo um contexto ao invés de falar apenas de regras de negócio.

### Visão

A visão de um sistema determina o que é o sistema, o que ele deve fazer, qual o objetivo, qual problema ele pretende resolver, qual o público que ele pretende atender e outras questões relacionados ao negócio do sistema e sua viabilidade. Essas características determinam uma fronteira e dá uma chance aos envolvidos na construção do sistema de entender o investimento que precisará ser feito para o seu completo desenvolvimento e assim decidir se vale ou não a pena continuar com a empreitada. É a parte mais importante do sistema porque é nessa parte que se determina os limites do sistema.

Normalmente pequenos empreendedores não fazem isso. As pessoas tem ideias baseadas em necessidades ou de automatizar algum negócio que já funciona de forma manual ou para criar soluções para problemas de uma forma diferente, inovadora. As vezes a solução é bastante simples e não é necessário entender todo o escopo para iniciar, mas as vezes é fundamental para não se perder no caminho.

Quando essa parte não é considerada, os projetos de sistemas geralmente começam e geralmente não terminam porque suas fronteiras não foram delimitadas. A visão é importante para dar uma direção clara para o projeto que vai dar vida ao sistema.

### Análise

Essa é a parte mais controversa, na minha opinião, no processo de desenvolvimento do sistema. É uma parte onde é preciso empregar algumas técnicas que podem ser científicas (segundo as pessoas que usam Engenharia de Software) ou empíricas (segundo as pessoas que não conhecem Engenharia de Software) na tentativa de entender o problema que o sistema quer resolver. Algumas vezes ao conversar com os usuários que tem o problema a ser resolvido pode-se descobrir que a solução não é um sistema, ou muito pior, pode-se entender errado o problema e dar uma solução para um problema que não existia. =)

### Requisitos

Os requisitos são a transformação das ideias e da análise dos problemas que o sistema quer resolver em partes que determinam "o que" o sistema deve ter para atender as necessidades dos usuários e assim resolver os problemas propostos na visão. Algumas metodologias seguem com uma análise direta das necessidades do negócio e outras tentam mapear processos já existentes, na tentativa de extrair essas necessidades e ao mesmo tempo direcionar o desenvolvimento da solução. Essa segunda abordagem normalmente é mais usada quando um processo de negócio já funciona ou já foi analisado/melhorado. A primeira abordagem também pode não só servir ao desenvolvimento do sistema como também o desenvolvimento de um processo, quando ele não existe.

Ao pensar nesses requisitos, o programador, que normalmente é uma pessoa que entende da parte de como desenvolver, de que linguagens usar, de que componentes são necessários, que banco de dados é melhor, que tecnologias são mais adequadas, que plataforma de desenvolvimento é mais ágil, que tipo de teste precisa ser feito, etc., normalmente não foca no "o que" o sistema precisa fazer e sim "como" ele deve fazer.

Nesse ponto é que entra as tais regras de negócio. Ou seja, sempre que um sistema é construído para resolver um problema ele terá restrições que deve atender para que possa alcançar o objetivo de forma eficaz. Normalmente as pessoas que escrevem essas regras de negócio são pessoas que entendem do negócio em si e o que precisa ser resolvido e nem sempre é o próprio desenvolvedor. As vezes essas regras não são apenas para que o sistema funcione corretamente, mas também para que atenda algum norma, alguma lei.

As regras de negócio serão derivadas dessa "lista" de requisitos porque ao tentar entender o requisito surgirão perguntas do tipo "como isso é calculado?", "que formato deve ter esse relatório?", "que formato devo enviar isso para o governo?", "qual a relação entre esse percentual e esse dado que o usuário informou?", "qual informação é solicitada primeiro?", etc.

Todas essas questões vão surgindo conforme os requisitos vão sendo entendidos e detalhados e essas regras de negócio podem ser mais ou menos complexas conforme os envolvidos vão explorando as possibilidades tecnológicas. Por isso, muitas vezes essas regras não estão claras no início do sistema e vão surgindo conforme as pessoas vão entendendo o negócio e os requisitos. Algumas vezes, o negócio já é bem claro no início do desenvolvimento e algumas regras já são conhecidas e precisam apenas ser atendidas.

### Outras Fases

Implementação, Teste, Instalação e outras fases surgem na sequência. É claro que cada metodologia explora essas fases com uma visão diferente, em ciclos diferentes, com diferentes abordagens, mas no geral essas são as fases que são sistematizadas em uma "Fabricação de Software".